# Using Script# in an old project

Tags: visual-studio-2012, script#

I have an old project (written by someone else) that makes use of Script#.  I've never used this tool before, so this question might seem rudimentary to some.  Anyway, I tried to open the solution, but some of the projects fail to load because of this line:

```
<Import Project="$(ProgramFiles)\ScriptSharp\v1.0\ScriptSharp.targets" />
```

I've installed Script# as described [here](https://github.com/nikhilk/scriptsharp/wiki/Building,-Installing-and-Testing) but it still doesn't create that folder.

So, how can I get around this so that I can open/build the projects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change that old `<Import/>` statement to

`<Import Project="..\packages\ScriptSharp.0.8\tools\ScriptSharp.targets" />`

and add scriptsharp with Nuget.

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it.  However, installing Script# from nuget created folder ScriptSharp.0.7.5.1 and not ScriptSharp.0.8.  Where can I get the 0.8 version?

Comment: The released version is 0.7.x. For 0.8, you need to get the CC branch and build it yourself. Check the instructions @ https://github.com/nikhilk/scriptsharp/wiki/Building,-Installing-and-Testing. You will need to point your project to the private nuget package source.